# Android device RAM usage increases but not application memory until device gets hanged

Tags: android, memory, memory-leaks, ram

I have an app which loads an activity A (consisting ListFragment), from A i load Activity B.. If i keep on switching between these two activities i see the device RAM goes up by 10 mb every time i switch. On Samsung devices we can use Task manager to "Clear memory" which basically clears up the RAM , but even if i do so , the memory does not get cleared up .Even if i Force stop the app and again clear memory , it does not go down.. Finally after switching between these 2 activites , the phone slows down and hangs once RAM is full and i have to restart the device. Interestingly the memory of the app does not go over 14-15 mb when checked using "dumpsys meminfo". I dont get OOM for my app.
This behavior observed on samsung galaxy tab 2 4.0,galaxy grand, ace duos. Its not observed on Nexus devices like Nexus 7 or Galaxy Nexus.
Why does the RAM keep going up but app memory not? Is this because of any BITMAP leaks ? I tried using MAT but i have just started using it so probably it will take some time to figure out how to identify a leak.. Any guesses ?

**EDIT**
I am using Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT flag while starting both activities.

Answer (score 3):

When you switch activities you should set the flags on the intent with:

Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT

That way, if the activity is already on the stack it will switch to it rather than starting a new one.

Comment: I forgot to mention but i hv already used that flag.. multiple instances of activities are not created